# Feasibility of phenyl migration

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

I am learning the fundamentals of organic chemistry,
here is the reaction which got me stumbling me for hours,
in the below reaction i could see that the amine group would get converted into diazonium salt, but i am clueless how to proceed further..

[image: Question]

The compund A(solution) is given below, it seems like a phenyl group has migrated to the adjacent carbon, i have never seen something like this and it is also not clear for me why a carbonyl group is formed in the middle. Overall I dont understand the reaction...it would be helpful if someone points out what did i miss out in reading that made me unfit to solve this problem. Thank you!

[image: Answer]

Comment: It is a carbocation rearrangement, common in organic chemistry. Did you heard Pinacol Pinacolone Rearrangement? This is similar to that.

Comment: yeah i got it....but i forgot to mention in the question about the product's sterochemistry, hope u would add on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to pinacol-pinacolone rearrangement. Only difference is in pinacol-pinacolone rearrangement, carbocation forms by dehydration while here, it forms through diazonium reaction. Following is the tentative mechanism of the rearrangement:

[image: pinacol-pinacolone rearrangement]

Since reaction progress through carbocation intermediate, the final product is a racemic mixture. $\ce{CH3-C+-CH3}$ (in pinacol) or $\ce{CH3-C+-H}$ (in given compound) can rotate about middle horizontal bond before alkyl or aryl group migration.

Comment: When phenyl is the migrating group there is also the possibility of an electrophilic aromatic substitution mechanism at the ipso position (i.e. forming a cyclopropane intermediate) followed by deprotonation of the O-H bond and breaking the C-O bond.